# SwiftKey Select/Copy/Cut/Paste/other shortcuts

Tags: swiftkey

`Swype` has a great feature of sliding between the `Swype` key and:

- `a` - Select all
- `c` - Copy
- `x` - Cut
- `v` - Paste
- `m` - Open selection in Google Maps
- `g` - Google for selection

It's much quicker than long-pressing and then (for example) going into the `More` menu for `Select All`.

Can SwiftKey do something like this?

(Feel free to tell me any other killer shortcuts while you're at it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 years later and Swype being unfortunately dead my solution was to switch back to Gboard.

Apparently Swiftkey doesn't give a s**t to customers needs.